# Clean directory pathname php

Tags: php, file, path

basically what i want to do is:

```
include($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Problem is, that this is not safe.
It would be safe, if it would point to `"/allowed/directory/"` or it's subdirectories.
So i test for that with startsWith("/allowed/directory/").

However I'm still afraid of something like:

```
"allowed/directory/../../bad/directory"
```

Is there a way to check whether a string points to a specific directory or one of it's 
subdirectories in php?

(Basically apply all the /../ - or am i missing another security flaw?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've determined the prefix is correct, you can use preg_match like this:

```
if(preg_match("#^[A-Za-z0-9/]+#", $string) {
    // correct
}
else {
    // incorrect
}
```

The variable part you're checking (non-static part) you typically want to be just alpha numeric.

As long as you're using `include` to include local PHP fils and properly validate your input (keeping that input simple) you *should* be fine. Just be extremely careful and test things throughly. You typically want to avoid passing user input into sensitive functions such as `include`. But with a framework, it's sometimes difficult to avoid that.

Another thing you could do is have a list of valid inputs to do an exact comparison. You could have this in an ini file and load it with [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php). This is usually the safest thing to do, just a little more work. You can also use a PHP file with an array, which works better with [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).

Comment: I'm using a preg_match("#^[A-Za-z0-9/_]+\.php#", $url) now. Quite similar to yours, but basically enforcese a .php to be included and allowes underscores. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

PHP function `realpath()` should remove the ../ /// from the path.

Though you are right, this can be a fairly dangerous operation. IMO the paths should be restricted to a known set of characters (like "a-zA-Z_" and / ).  Also, path strings should be limited to a known size (like 256 chars).